# Run scripts before and after sleep

Tags: fedora, services, suspend, sleep

I need to run some scripts before and after my system (Fedora 33) goes into sleep mode. So far I tried two different approaches and they both have failed.

First was to place the commands and script files here: `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/pre-suspend.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash/
if [ "${1}" == "pre" ]; then
#
elif [ "${1}" == "post" ]; then
    /path/to//scripts/script1
fi
```

The second approach was to create the following 2 `systemd` service files with the needed instructions:

- `/etc/systemd/system/pre-sleep.service`
- `/etc/systemd/system/post-sleep.service`

Sample:
*`/etc/systemd/system/pre-sleep.service`*

```
[Unit]
Description=Run before sleep
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=sleep.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/bash /path/to//scripts/script1
TimeoutStartSec=0

[Install]
RequiredBy=sleep.target
```

Then, I reloaded the systemd manager configuration:
`systemctl daemon-reload`

If I check the status, it returns as loaded but inactive:

```
systemctl status pre-sleep.service
● pre-sleep.service - Run before sleep
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/pre-sleep.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
```

What am I missing?